# Jmeter. Как сохранить глобально значение переменной из запроса?

Tags: jmeter

Сохраняю значение переменной с помощью `vars.putObject();` Как сохранить это глобально?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [Functions and Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

> Properties are not the same as variables. **Variables are local to a thread; properties are common to all threads**, and need to be referenced using the __P or __property function.

Так что используйте вместо `vars` переменную `props`, которая по сути является инстансом [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html)

```
props.put("foo", 123);
```

Альтернатива - функция [__setProperty()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__setProperty)

Вытащить значение можно либо `props.get("foo")` либо используя функцию [__P()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P)

- [Knit One Pearl Two: How to Use Variables in Different Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/knit-one-pearl-two-how-use-variables-different-thread-groups)

Comment: props.put - сохранит объект?